# pgf tikz for LaTeX how can I use x and y coordinates with node

Tags: latex, tikz, pgf

I have the following rectangle:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thin] (0,0) -- (7,0) -- (7,5) -- (7,5) -- (0,5) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and I want to put a text label for the width and height of the rectangle using node. But don't know how to specify the x, y coordinates for the text label.

Can I use x,y coordinates with node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using the `at (x, y)` syntax:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thin] (0,0) -- (7,0) -- (7,5) -- (7,5) -- (0,5) -- (0,0);
  \node at (3.5, -0.5) {7cm};
  \node at (-0.5, 2.5) {5cm};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, you've made my life a little easier

Comment: I'm happy to know I helped. Anything you want me to clarify to accept the answer?